# Understanding SPDY latency claims

Tags: spdy

Reading the SPDY whitepaper at http://dev.chromium.org/spdy/spdy-whitepaper, it seems like supporting it will improve my HTTP latency. However, I'm not clear on a few of the claims.

1) "Because HTTP can only fetch one resource at a time (HTTP pipelining helps, but still enforces only a FIFO queue), a server delay of 500 ms prevents reuse of the TCP channel for additional requests." -- Where did this 500ms number come from?

2) "We discovered that SPDY's latency savings increased proportionally with increases in packet loss rates, up to a 48% speedup at 2%." -- But doesn't putting all the requests on a single TCP connection mean that congestion control will slow down all your requests whereas is you had multiple connections, 1 TCP stream would slow down but others would not?

3) "[With pipelining] any delays in the processing of anything in the stream (either a long request at the head-of-line or packet loss) will delay the entire stream." -- This implies that packet loss would not delay the entire stream using SPDY. Why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 500ms reference is simply an example, the number can be 50ms or 5s, but the point is still the same: HTTP forces FIFO processing, which results in inefficient use of the underlying TCP connection. As the paper notes, pipelining can help in theory, but in practice pipeline is not used due to many intermediaries which break when you turn it on. Hence, you're stuck with the worst case scenario: full RTT + server processing time, and FIFO ordering.

Re, packet loss. Yup, you're exactly right. One of the downsides of using a single connection is that in the case of packet loss, the throughput of the entire connection is cut in half, as opposed to 1/2 of one of the N connections in flight. Having said that, there are also some benefits! For example, when you saturate a single connection, you get much faster recovery due to triple ACK's + potentially much wider congestion windows to begin with.. Due to the fact that most HTTP transfers are relatively small (tens of KB's), it is not unusual for many connections to terminate even before they exit the slow-start phase!

Re, pipelining. Lost packet would delay the stream - that's TCP. The win is in eliminating head-of-line blocking, which enables a lot more and a lot smarter optimization by the browser, followed by some of the wins I described above.

Comment: Thanks. But how do you explain the SPDY claim that it "INCREASES latency savings proportionally" in the face of packet loss? As you wrote, shouldn't the multi-connection approach have handled packet loss better?

Comment: In practice, SPDY improves latency by removing FIFO and head-of-line blocking. Even with packet loss, it still comes out ahead.

Answer (score 1):

@GroovyDotCom: Here's some hands-on proof of HTTP2's (SPDY's) performance benefits:

http://www.httpvshttps.com/